# Redirect domain to second preserving prefix-subdomain

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I am working with HAProxy and want to be able to redirect all traffic from domainA to a second domainB preserving the prefix/subdomain.

I have tried things like:

```
redirect prefix http://www.domainA.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i http://www.domainB.com }
```

which works but I may have several other domains each having sub-domains.

I want to be able to do something like

```
redirect prefix http://*.domainA.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i http://*.domainB.com }
redirect prefix http://*.domainA.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i http://*.domainC.org }
```

Domains B & C are effectively aliases for domainA in this instance.
Is there a way of doing this so I only need on entry per alias domain?

To further increase complexity I would ideally want to ignore what protocol the inbound request comes in (`http`/`https`) and redirect to `https`

For this instance I would be looking at doing something like

```
redirect prefix http://*.domainA.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i (http|https)://*.domainB.com }
redirect prefix http://*.domainA.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i (http|https)://*.domainC.org }
```

Answer (score 3):

I posted one solution for that in a different thread ([Use haproxy to redirect *.domain1.com/* to *.domain2.com/*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405301/373748)
).

```
acl domain_redirect hdr_end(host) -i domain1.com
http-request set-var(req.new_host) req.hdr(host),regsub(domain1\.com$,domain2.com,i) if domain_redirect
http-request redirect prefix https://%[var(req.new_host)] code 301 if { var(req.new_host) -m found }
```

As I mentioned there, this solution has at least one shortcoming, in that it seems to discard anchors from the URL. For example:

```
domain1.com?foo=bar#ze-anchor -> domain2.com?foo=bar
```